# gsp dropdown value returned as NaN in IE7 document mode(javascript)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, nan

I am reading a index value of a dropdown of a gsp page through javascript. The js function works in all the browsers except in IE7 document mode. The js returns the value as NaN in IE7 DOCMODE. Tried for more than half a day,but am not able to find the reason. Any help/suggestion is really appreciated. Copying the js function for your reference.

`<script>var encodedMonthRange = new Array();
    <g:each in="${ReportService.RangeList()}" var="mRange">
    encodedMonthRange.push('${mRange?.encodeAsBase64()}');
    function encodeParams(){
    var index =Number(document.getElementById("monthRange").selectedIndex);
    alert("Index : " + index.toString());
    var encodedVal = encodedMonthRange[index];
    alert(encodedVal);
    document.getElementById("monthRangeEncoded").value = encodedVal;
    document.getElementById("historyOverview").submit();
    }
    <script>`

Html code:

`<div class="fl" style="padding-right:20px;">
    <g:select id="monthRange" class="lstBox autocolor autoWidth" from="${ReportService.RangeList()}"
    valueMessagePrefix="filter" value="${params.monthRange}" onchange="encodeParams()" />
    </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `.toString` call:

```
function encodeParams() {
    var index = document.getElementById("monthRange").selectedIndex;//index always number
    alert("Index : " + index.toString()); //add to String call
    var encodedVal = encodedMonthRange[index];
    alert(encodedVal);
    document.getElementById("monthRangeEncoded").value = encodedVal;
    document.getElementById("historyOverview").submit();
}
```

P.S. May be `encodedMonthRange` it not defined?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have tried the above as you said, but this caused my js function not to work(no action after the dropdown change). But, again this works in all other browsers except in IE7 DOCMODE. 

The existing js ends up in `requested page not found` error(only in IE7 docmode,works fine in other browsers). I think IE is not able to   read the index value of the dropdown in IE7 DOCMODE.

Comment: May be problem is not in this code? Can you add all code or create `jsfiddle`?

Comment: I am sure that the problem is not with the whole code, but with the way I read the index value. IE 7 is not able to read that field using `document.getElementById("monthRange").selectedIndex;`. I tried printing the `index` value in all the other browsers and is getting printed as expected. 

Also I have all the needed other js functions also. I cannot paste the whole code as it is very big. Added the needed part of the code.